# How can i get swf movie duration by php?

Tags: php, flash

i need swf movie duration by php. for example i have 3 swf movie on my site, and i want to play another exactly than, when first one ends. i found a small library here

> http://php.net/manual/en/book.swf.php

but i cant understand, is it worth? it has no documentation at all.

i want my php code to find swf movies on site, (no matter how many they will be) and play One after another. if php can not do this perfectly, what is another way or solution? javascript? i search google and nothing.

please help ...

Comment: Can you influence what is in the Flash movies? i.e. do you compile them, or are they ready-made and unchangeable?

Comment: no they are simple swf movies, unchangable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP extension you mention actually has some docs, [even an example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/swf.examples-basic.php) - but it is used to create swf animations programmatically.

To determine the length of an existing flash movie (I suppose you mean `.flv` since you speak about *movies*), I suggest you use a command line utility like `extract` (from libextractor):

```
$ LC_ALL=C extract Musik/barsandtone.flv 
format - 44100 Hz, 16-bit, stereo, MP3, 96.0000 kbps
format - 360x288, 10.00 fps, On2 TrueMotion VP6, 400.0000 kbps
duration - 6.00 s
mimetype - video/x-flv
```